# Which one is better or must be in PHP scripts that can be applied for real projects?

Tags: php, html

As I am learning PHP, I want to know if I ever wanted to put HTML tags in the middle of a PHP script, I want to know which one is better or must be, out of putting them in PHP *echo* or breaking the PHP script where the HTML has to be started and then continuing the PHP script using tags php starting and closing tags. Below are two examples where you can get a clear idea.

```
page name: home.php example: 1
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    <?php
     a=0;
    while (a<=10){
   ?>
   <input type = "text" max-length="20">
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </body>
 </html>

 page name: home.php example: 2
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    <?php
    a=0;
    while (a<=10){
   echo "<input type = 'text' max-length='20'>";
   }
   ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Is there an option 3 as I wouldn't do it either way?

Comment: first one, its cleaner
if you use second approach and insert HTML in PHP , it will look dirty and there will be no syntax highlighting for HTML
if you are starting, you shouldn't worry about performance

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how would you do then?

Comment: I personally would use example 2

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes I will suggest you use `<?php ?>` and `<?= ?>` to break out of HTML. Echo’ing HTML may confuse you while learning (as someone earlier pointed out code highlighting). In your journey through learning, consider learning about MVC and how you can apply in simple ways to fit your needs. It helps you separate presentation from logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a matter of preference, both are acceptable.  Typically if you have quite a bit of HTML DOM to insert, you'd break php with `?>` and then reopen when necessary.  If you have just a single line of HTML that needs to be inserted, a simple echo works perfectly.

Comment: Can I know which one is better out of them in performance wise or memory wise?